# Why do people say "Happy" Halloween?

Tags: idioms, halloween

Shouldn't it be "horror filled halloween" or "spooky halloween"?  It fits the purpose of the day. Why "happy"? By the way "Happy Halloween everybody!"

Comment: As the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween) says: It's an evening of celebration and remeberance. Also it is unnatural/unintuitive to wish someone a horrible anything.

Comment: "Happy Halloween" has been a well-wishing greeting for [over 100 years](http://stores.pattysantiquepostcards.com/-strse-1555/Antique%2C-collectible%2C-post-cards%2C/Detail.bok). Alliteration might have played a role in popularizing the greeting – who knows? This isn't to say that "Have a spooky Halloween" _isn't_ used (in fact, [it is](http://www.cherishables.com/card/AT1DIR1.htm)), but it may not be as common as "Happy Halloween." Heck, you can use [_jolly_](http://stores.pattysantiquepostcards.com/-strse-1923/Antique%2C-collectible-old-post/Detail.bok) if you want; don't overthink it :^)

Comment: Hallowe'en is celebrated in the UK and has been in various ways for centuries, but people don't really greet each other with "Happy Hallowe'en!" which sounds very American.

Comment: Actually, it's HUGELY American!  ***Happy Halloween everyone!*** :-)>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The wish for a "Happy" Halloween is a wish for the person to enjoy the day, regardless of how little or how much spookiness they wish for on that day.

Likewise, "Happy Christmas" is a common expression in the UK, wishing for an enjoyable Christmas.

Though it is true that people attempt to wish one another a "Spooky Halloween", this simply hasn't caught on in popularity, and "Horrible Halloween" would be similiar to telling someone to "Have a Rotten Day!", the connotation of you wishing them a bad day is just too overpowering to make it work.

The alliteration of "Happy Halloween" also likely helps keep it in its place as a popular greeting and well-wishing for the day.

Answer (score 7):

"Happy" is just the generic modifier for holidays.  I can think only of Christmas as an exception to the rule ("*Merry* Christmas").

Comment: Which it isn't in the UK.  They just say "Happy Christmas".

Comment: Is Christmas the only Holiday that doesn't have Happy before it (in US English)?

Comment: I can think of no other holiday that does not get predecessed by "Happy".

Comment: @krikara There are some "holidays" that aren't happy and would be weird to be proceeded by "happy".  Yom Kippur is the best example I can think of.

Comment: @Zibbobz  Really? Is it a case of 'Happy Martin Luther King Day'? And 'Happy George Washington's Birthday Day'? Or do they just say 'Happy birthday George'?

Comment: @WS2 I believe the first case would be correct.  "Happy Martin Luther King Jr. Day".

Comment: @Amory I have actually heard people say "Happy Yom Kippur", as odd as it might sound.

Comment: @Zibbobz Me too, but that doesn't make it right, or common.

Comment: @Amory True.  I didn't say it was either. Just that people do it.  Sometimes people say things without realizing they should not.

Comment: @Amory I'm not sure "Happy" suits Easter either.  Even though it's celebratory, it's really too significant to be trivialized by "Happy." Despite the fact that "Joyful Easter" would probably be a better fit, "Happy Easter" is still pretty universal. If Yom Kippur ever becomes commercialized, I'm sure people will prepend "Happy" to it as well.

Comment: @Zibbobz: We do say "Merry Christmas" in British English, e.g. "[Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/legacy/bbcinternet/2011/12/blog_closing_xmas_2011.html)" (BBC).

Answer (score 4):

Because people say happy "everything" now.  It is like a drone sentence that gets repeated by the non-thinking masses.  Happy Monday.  Happy Thursday.  Happy Columbus Day (I heard this a couple weeks ago).  Happy roll back the clock weekend!

This might be the masses or it could be Hallmark.  If you put the word "Happy" in front of any phrase then they can sell millions of cards for each "Happy" phrase.  Happy answer.

Comment: Yay, happy answer \o/